# Differents pieces of code based on same template don't produce the same result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

In one of the pages of my project, I have a list of itens, where for each item from the list, there is this piece of code:

```
    <div id="edit_evento_${item.id}_2" class="row">
        <form method="post" action="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/evento/altera_evento"/>" id="target">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${item.id}">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            Edi&ccedil;&atilde;o de evento
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <table id="hor-minimalist-a">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Atributo</th>
                        <th>Valor</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td> Nome: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="nome" value="${item.nome}" size=20 maxlength=40> </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td> Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="descricao" value="${item.descricao}" size=30 maxlength=100> </tdv>
                    </td>

                    <tr>
                        <td> <h3>Periodo da Data</h3> </td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>inicio: <input type="text" id="data_inicial" name="data_inicial" value="<c:out value="${item.dataInicial}"/>"/> </td>
                                    <td>final: <input type="text" id="data_final" name="data_final" value="<c:out value="${item.dataFinal}"/>"/> </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td> <h3>Periodo do Hor&aacute;rio</h3> </td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>inicio: <input type="text" id="hora_inicial" name="hora_inicial" value="${item.horaInicial}"/> </td>
                                    <td> final: <input type="text" id="hora_final" name="hora_final" value="${item.horaFinal}"/> </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td> Dura&ccedil;&atilde;o: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="duracao" value="${item.duracao}" size=20 maxlength=2> Minutos </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> <div id="result"></div> </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Salvar</button> <br/>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Related to this code, I have this Jquery code, which is executed for each item of the list:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#data_inicial').datepicker({
            inline: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],

        });
        $('#data_final').datepicker({
            inline: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
        });
        $('#hora_inicial').timepicker();
        $('#hora_final').timepicker();
    });
</script>
```

My problem is that only the first item of the list have the expected behaviour for each element of the form. The other itens neither open the date/time pickers neither are capturing the output from the submit operation and displaying it in the proper .

Anyone can see what I am doing wrong?

ps.: The complete code for this page is this:

https://github.com/klebermo/webapp_horario_livre/blob/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/evento/lista.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that piece of code is written out multiple times, you will end up with multiple items that all have the same id 'data_inicial' or 'data_final'. Apart from the fact that is will produce invalid HTML, it will also result in jQuery running only once since jQuery will look for a single unique item with that ID.

You should replace the ID with a class with the same name

```
<td>inicio: <input type="text" class="data_inicial" name="data_inicial" value="<c:out value="${item.dataInicial}"/>"/> </td>
<td>final: <input type="text" class="data_final" name="data_final" value="<c:out value="${item.dataFinal}"/>"/> </td>
```

and change the hashes in your jQuery code with dots:

```
    $('.data_inicial').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],

    });
    $('.data_final').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
    });
```

The same goes for your time pickers...

Answer (score 1):

In the code you link to on line 38 you are using `<c:forEach var="item" items="${lista}">` to iterate over a number of items. Inside that foreach you are creating a number of tags with `id` attributes that end up with the same values. `id` attributes in HTML must be unique on a page.

If you want to use jQuery UI's datepicker on several input fields then let those fields have a `class` attribute and use that as the selector instead of the id selector you are using now.

E.g. change:

```
<tr>
    <td>inicio: <input type="text" id="data_inicial" name="data_inicial" value="<c:out value="${item.dataInicial}"/>"/> </td>
    <td>final: <input type="text" id="data_final" name="data_final" value="<c:out value="${item.dataFinal}"/>"/> </td>
</tr>
```

to

```
<tr>
    <td>inicio: <input type="text" class="data_inicial" name="data_inicial" value="<c:out value="${item.dataInicial}"/>"/> </td>
    <td>final: <input type="text" class="data_final" name="data_final" value="<c:out value="${item.dataFinal}"/>"/> </td>
</tr>
```

and alter the selectors used in your script tag:

```
 $('.data_inicial').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],

    });
 $('.data_final').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
    });
```